# lvremove a snapshot: "-real" files left around, what are they, safe to remove?

Tags: lvm

I removed a snapshot volume with lvremove. It says it successfully removed it. But I noticed there is a "-real" file still in /dev/mapper. I believe these "-real" files are somehow associated with snapshots, because when I've created and removed snapshots before, these have come and gone as well.

So, I'm wondering what these files are, and whether it's safe for me to remove them?

UPDATE 08/06/2015: 
with the right google terms ("lvm snapshot /dev/mapper files"), I was able to find the following page which describes these files: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Logical_Volume_Manager_Administration/device_mapper.html
Currently in the process of reading the page to find out what the files are and how to deal with them.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the aforementioned document and much playing around on my system in an attempt to understand what's going on, I think I have answer.

the "real" file is a copy of the device map table for the original LV before any snapshots were created. The map table for the "real" file looks exactly the same as the map table for the original LV. It is a linear device type, meaning reads and writes occur as you would expect, with the same major and minor numbers and the same offsets and length. In my case the major/minor numbers refer to the actual hard drive /dev/sdb1.

In other words: before snapshot is created:

- original LV --> some area on hard disk /dev/sdb1

After snapshot is created:

- REAL file --> same area on hard disk /dev/sdb1. linear mapping. regular block device. Theoretically should be able to mount this just as you can mount the original LV, but I haven't tried it.
- original LV --> somewhere else

Now original LV is type "snapshot-origin" pointing to the new "real" device:

- original LV --> major/minor for REAL file (253/x = MD array, not /dev/sdb1). This is not a regular block device.

The original LV is now a type "snapshot-origin". This means reads and writes don't occur in the normal fashion anymore. Reads occur from the REAL device normally, but writes first copy the original data to a COW device, then later to the "real" device.

In addition, there is now a COW device and a SNAPSHOT device/volume.

- COW --> brand new area on the hard drive. linear mapping.
- SNAPSHOT --> REAL + COW. snapshot mapping

Old data is written to COW. it's just a regular block device that you can read and write to normally.

SNAPSHOT is not a regular block device. It is a "snapshot" device. Reads from SNAPSHOT will not return new data. Will read either from COW or REAL depending on where old data is.

In my scenario, when I tried to lvremove the snapshot, it gave me the following error:
Device vol0-xxxx-real (253:15) is used by another device.
  Failed to resume xxxx.
  Releasing activation in critical section.

the snapshot volume was not removed. But, repeating the lvremove again, reported success. Snapshot volume gone. BUT "real" devices still existing in /dev/mapper. Map tables for origin volumes back to "linear" pointing to underlying hardware as they should be.

So, my assessment is that as long as the map table for the origin volume is the same as it was before the snapshot was created (meaning it should identically match the map table for the "real" device), this means it's pointing to where it should. As long as map tables on other devices are not referencing the major/minor numbers of the "REAL" device, then it is safe to remove the "REAL" device(s) that should have been removed automatically by the lvremove command.

As to how this error occured in the first place, one thing I noticed is:
- if my original volume contains partitions, and I create a snapshot, a "real" device is created for the LV but no "real" devices are created for the partitions in it. In this case, lvremove works without error.

- however, on my problematic system, there were "real" devices for each partition within the LV. I don't know how they got there. Maybe these were LVs-within-LVs and the snapshotting mechanism got confused??